# In C++, what is the recommended way to create 'n' number of objects, where n is user defined. How can I do this?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want the number of objects that my program creates, to be controlled by the user. What are the different ways to do this and when should I choose one approach over another?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class
{
public :
   int FullName;
   int RollNumber;
   in
{
public :
   int FullName;
   int RollNumber;
   int age;
   int marks;
}
voidt age;
   int marks;
};
void main()
{
   int n;
   cout << "How many Students record you want :\t ";
   cin >>n;     
   Data Student[n];
}
```

Comment: you are already reading into `n` the entered value, so what exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: You're looking for `std::vector`.

Comment: Two basic approaches.  Get a count of things to read in, then read in that many.  Or read in things until you get some sort of terminator which indicates "no more items to read in".

Answer (score 0):

Like said before, use std::vector.

Your example however seems to work:
https://onlinegdb.com/HyHjwZddQ

Comment: This is called a *variable length array* (*VLA*) and is not a part of the standard C++. It is a compiler extension. `std::vector` **is** the preferred way.

Comment: Stuff like `Data Student[n];` isn't valid C++, because [C++ doesn't have variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/9254539). Code like this only compiles because of a GCC non-standard extension. You should use an `std::vector` instead to make your code portable and avoid blowing out the stack.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of items becomes fixed at the moment of creation, your best option is

```
std::make_unique<Data[]>(n)
```

But if you might need to change the group of items later (insert or remove), then

```
std::vector<Data>(n)
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using an array directly (on the heap) over an std::vector which also uses the heap? Both have the same memory lay out after all. If you need to insert or remove I would rather use a list.

Comment: @FrederikDeRuyck: Neither suggestion is to "use an array directly".  I suggested the smart pointer with fewer operations, when those are sufficient, and the smart pointer with more operations when you need them.  And locality/cache efficiency means a linked list usually loses to contiguous storage even on insert and remove.